# Lowest secure value for minSdkVersion

Tags: android, sdk

I am new in this Android world.
At first I setted up Manifest to work with Sdk Version 10 (Android 2.3.3) because my phone was that way.
Now I have created an application and I would like to know if I am free to reduce the minSdkVersion value for earlier versions, and how much.
Is there a way to know (at Compile time) if code will be compatible?

I use Alarm Manager, audio manager, set wallpaper, write to disk, boot on and off persmission... and other several things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can reduce the level of sdk api if you do not use upper element API. if you use eclipse, it will notify your error directly in the code

Comment: if you are referring to the errors I am thinking of then Eclipse will only "warn" you if you utilize a method below the "target" api and not the minimum api.

Comment: a warning is a notification, that is what we need right? Furthermore a method of a lowest API is not a problem, the reverse is not true.

Comment: what I was trying to note is the difference between minimum sdk and target sdk.  The wanring you are describing would only be affected by changing the target sdk as far as I understand what you are trying to accomplish.